# Attach invoice to event registration emails even if transaction is not taxed

Tags: civievent, contributions, taxes

Is it possible to attach invoices to confirmation emails for event registrations, if the payment transaction is not taxed?

From what I've observed, currently, invoices are only attached when a transaction has non-zero tax amount.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Usually the next step would be to try to replicate it on the demo site but as the demo sites don't send emails, that's tricky. If you can replicate it reliably on an out-of-the-box, up-to-date CiviCRM, then consider filing a bug report - see https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the following bug:

[Event or contribution payment invoices are not being attached in confirmation emails, when the tax amount is 0 or evaluates to false.](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16789)

Fixed in 4.6.5 .

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell in the docs, this is "tax invoice" functionality. It is not a system for generic invoicing. I think tax invoices are a country-specific feature, perhaps related to VAT.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the System Workflow Messages (civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1) so that if the transaction is Pay Later, it will replace the word Receipt with the word Invoice

ie

{if $is_pay_later}{ts}Tax Invoice{/ts}{else}{ts}Tax Receipt{/ts}{/if}

Hope that helps